# Best data structure to represent food objects, and quantity

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, structure

I have a problem in Java where i have a **RecipeBook**, which contains **Recipes**, and each of them is composed of **Food**, and **its corresponding amount**.

Recipe example: "Lemon pie recipe":

- Lemon, 2
- Flour, 6
- Sugar, 5
- Egg, 2

The problem says that food amount can vary through recipes, e.g in lemon pie recipe, lemon has 2 units but in guacamole recipe lemon has 3 units.

So my question is, what is the best data structure to represent the food and the food amount together? I've created a Recipe class, which has an `ArrayList<ArrayList> foods` attribute where i keep the Food object, and the quantity. Like in the example: <<Lemon, 2>, <Flour, 6>, <Sugar, 5>, <Egg, 2>> but i don't know if this is the best way to implement the recipe list.

Answer (score 1):

A separate class `Recipe` should be implemented, including receipt name, a collection of ingredients, set of instructions what should be done with the ingredients.

In its turn, the receipt ingredients should contain information about the food, amount, and measurement unit of amount (pieces, grams/ounces, tablespoons/teaspoons, etc.).  Food may be represented as a `String` value for simplicity, or as a class/enum with more details (e.g. category, price, preparation, possible replacements, etc.)

```java
public class Ingredient {
    String food;
    Number amount;
    Unit unit;

// constructor(s), getters/setters
}

enum Unit {
    PIECE,
    GRAM,
    MILLILITER,
    TABLESPOON,
    TEASPOON;
}
```

The question *what is the best way of implementation* of the ingredient collection per recipe is actually an opinion-based one.  It may be done as a map:

```java
public class Recipe {
    String name;
    Map<String, Ingredient> ingredientsByNames;
    String instructions;
// constructor(s), getters/setters
}
```

or a list/set:

```java
public class Recipe {
    String name;
    List<Ingredient> ingredients;
    String instructions;
// constructor(s), getters/setters
}
```

Comment: This would have been my solution too. The Map<String, Integer> cannot represent "1.5 filled spoons" or something like "300 ml", so you definitely need a unit and that's why an Integer is definitely not the best choice. You could do with a Map<String, NumberWithUnit> or something similar though. **Important thing**: the key of a HashMap must implement the `hashCode` and `equal` methods the right way. See docs.

Answer (score 0):

Define a HashMap with name receipe in your class ReceipeBook

```
Map<String, Integer> receipe = new HashMap<>();
```

So, this doesn't have a fixed size, and you can add any number of items in the map using:

```
receipe.put("Lemon",2);
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

HashMap : recipe

```
Map<String, Integer> recipe = new HashMap<>();
```

Change to `Map<String, Double>` if units can be in decimal too.

This does not have fixed size and can be expanded dynamically.

Other option is to create 2 arraylist.One for food name and other for units.This will be useful if you want to traverse by index for eg usecase:

a) buy 10 units for food items (a:5, b:2,c:3)  starting from first.

b) You have 1000 bucks , buy maximum stuff keeping the priority from 1 to n in the list.